# The message inside the file is not printed

Tags: java

I have successfully create my directory and able to save file in that folder .However, as i run my program, it didn't print my message inside that file. The file was created but empty inside.For additional information,my program will keep generate new file if the sensor in my program stop.Can you guys help solve my problem why i can't print the message? [Here i attach some error in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjE14.png)

```
String savePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Data Sync Status";
File saveLocation = new File(savePath);
    if(!saveLocation.exists()){                             
         String myFile = "Data Sync Status/Lane Number"+ " " + getRemoteLane().getName();
        (new File(myFile)).mkdirs();                                
            try {
                 PrintWriter textFileWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));
                 textFileWriter.write("DTS Service Okay");
                 textFileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {                                   
                e.printStackTrace();
                    }

         }
```

Comment: Please post the Error Stacks in your question itself rather than posting an image to redirect URL. The Stack clearly says *"Access Denied!"* You'll have to give proper permissions first.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a directory instead of a file:

```
(new File(myFile)).mkdirs();
```

I think this should be:

```
new File(saveLocation).mkdirs();
```

Then you have missed to define the full path of the file. It must also contain the savePath

```
PrintWriter textFileWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(savePath + System.getProperty("file.separator") + myFile)));
```